# RegEx match character before digit but

Tags: regex

only after at least 3 characters and only one of those characters should be matched e.g. 
for `lumia820` the match should be `a8` but for `aa6` there should not be any match.
My current attempt is `/([a-z]{3,})([0-9])/`, however this wrongly includes the leading characters. This is probably an easy one for regex specialists but I am completely stuck here.. Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're in an environment that allows lookbehinds, you could do this:

```
/(?<=[a-z]{2,})([a-z][0-9])/
```

That will look for **two** or more letters right before what we want to capture, make sure that they're there without including them in the capture group, and then capture the third (or more) letter followed by the number. The capture itself will make sure that the third letter is there.

@HolyMac per your comment:

Note that I am using c#, and I'm not sure of the differences with Objective-C, but the following matches `f9` for me:

```
string testString = "abasfsdf9314";
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=[a-z]{2,})([a-z][0-9])");
Match match = regex.Match(testString);
```

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction, however it does not yet work on my regex playground http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ nor in my final environment Objective-C NSRegularExpression. Did you test this yourself or is there maybe just a typo?

Comment: @HolyMac check my edit. "Converting" my code to objective-c should do the trick for ya. It may have to do with the forward slashes -- you won't need them for most languages.

Comment: @HolyMac oh, it looks like in objective-c you have to *wrap* your lookbehind in `=`s. Try replacing `(?<=[a-z]{2,})` with `(?<=[a-z]{2,}=)`

Comment: Thanks a million Phillip, you are a regex hero. I settled with (?<=[a-z]{2})([a-z])([0-9]) as apparently Apples NSRegularexpressions have problems with the extra {2,} in the lookbehind statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you need at least 3, you can use `{2,}` to match 2 or more, and then capture the following character along with the next digit:

```
/[a-z]{2,}([a-z][\d])[\d]*/
```

- `[a-z]{2,}` matches at least 2 characters at the start. This ensures there are 2 or more characters *before* the one you capture.
- `([a-z][\d])` captures the next character followed by the first digit
- `[\d]*` matches any remaining trailing digits.

If this must be anchored, don't forget `^$`.

```
/^[a-z]{2,}([a-z][\d])[\d]*$/
```

#### JavaScript example:

```
// Matching example aabc9876 yields c9
"a string with aabc9876 and other stuff".match(/[a-z]{2,}([a-z][\d])[\d]*/)
// ["aabc9876", "c9"]

// Non-matching example with zx8 
"a string with zx8 should not match".match(/[a-z]{2,}([a-z][\d])[\d]*/)
// null
```

Comment: This seems to match the whole string not just the two characters, any more ideas?

Comment: @HolyMac In what language or regex engine? I only have `()` around what should match. You ought not be getting a capture for the whole string.

Comment: I use Apple's NSRegularexpressions as engine maybe that is the problem here. However your solution does not work on the  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ regexplayground either. Thanks for your outstanding explanation anyways, very well explained and theoretically should work.